# Circles and Tangents property

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

In the following figure

[image]

$AB=5$ and $BC=4$. I have to find radius of the sector. Somebody help me with this question

Comment: Use the [power of the point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $A$. It gives you a relation between $CD$ and $DA$: $DA^2-CD^2=5\cdot (5+4)$. Pythagoras gives you another: $DA^2+CD^2=(5+4)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how much geometry you have learned. Actually there are a variety of ways to solve this problem. The methods provided by MoonLightSyzygy both works. Here I just want to present a very fundamental solution.

We can draw a line orthogonal to $AC$ from $D$ intersecting $AC$ by $F$. In addition, we can just connect $B$ and $D$. Clearly, $CD=BD=r$, where $r$ is the radius of the sector. Thus, $\triangle BDC$ is an isosceles triangle. Thus, $F$ is also the midpoint of $BC$, implying that $CF=BF=BC/2=2$.

Also notice that $\triangle CDF$ is a right triangle, which is similar to $\triangle ACD$. Thus,

$$\frac{CF}{CD}=\frac{CD}{AC}\implies\frac{2}{r}=\frac{r}{4+5}\implies r^2=18\implies r=3\sqrt{2}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By Pythagoras we have $$(AE+r)^2 = 9^2-r^2\implies \boxed{AE^2+2rAE = 81-2r^2}$$

By the power of the point $A$ we have $$AB\cdot AC = AE\cdot (AE+2r)$$So

$$ 5\cdot 9 = 81-2r^2 \implies r=3\sqrt{2}$$